# Как исправить конфликт установки пакета Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

После подключения composer require --dev barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

получаю такие проблемы

Problem 1
- barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper v2.8.0 requires illuminate/console ^5.5 || ^6 || ^7 -> found illuminate/console[v5.5.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.5, v7.0.0, ..., v7.29.3] but
it conflicts with another require.
- barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper v2.8.1 requires illuminate/console ^6 || ^7 || ^8 -> found illuminate/console[v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.5, v7.0.0, ..., v7.29.3, v8.0.0, ..., v8.16.1] but it
conflicts with another require.
- Root composer.json requires barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper ^2.8 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper[v2.8.0, v2.8.1].

как можно исправить?

Версия фреймворка 5.4

версия Ide phpshtorm  2019.3.3

Comment: Добавьте информацию о версии фремворка, операционной системе, вашей `IDE`.

Comment: 2 варианта - обновить версию фреймворка или форкнуть пакет, проанализировать его логику, подправить что-нибудь и добавить этот пакет из своего репозитория. Мне кажется, легче свой проект обновить, нежели разбираться в чужом пакете

Answer (score 0):

При установке пакета, укажите его более раннюю версию.

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper:2.5.0
```